# Masonry and overlapping divs

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, jquery-masonry, masonry

I've been racking my brain trying to figure this out.  I'm using an AJAX call to populate a div with content (divs containing locally stored images and text).  The ajax call executes successfully, but the divs on the second row partially overlap the ones on the first row.

Here's the script I've been working with:

```
var $allF = $('#allItems');

$(document).ready(function () {

    $allF.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $allF.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.box',
            isAnimated: true,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 500,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            },
            isFitWidth: true,
            columnWidth: 10
        });
    });

    loadAllItems();

});

function loadAllItems() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Ajax/LoadAllItems',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { skip: (pageIndex * pageSize), take: pageSize },
        success: function (posts) {
            var items = '';
            $.each(posts, function(p, post) {
                items += 'html removed to keep post short';
            });

            var $itemBlock = $(items);
            $allF.append($itemBlock);
            $allF.masonry('appended', $itemBlock);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

All of the content items have the same width of 130px but the height of each item can vary by as much as 20 to 30 px.  Is there something that I've missed?  I've tried the Q&A on the masonry site but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Most probably you are experiencing this issue because of images are not loaded when you refresh the masonry, you should reload the masonry after the images have been fully loaded. Use https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded that

Comment: @SaqibAmin Thank you for the comment - I'll test it out here in a few.  One question, the jquery.masonry.min.js appears to contain a definition for imagesLoaded - what's the difference between this and what you've suggested?

Comment: There is no difference, Your package is already having the imagesloaded library included, you don't need to load it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your Ajax function like below:

```
function loadAllItems() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Ajax/LoadAllItems',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { skip: (pageIndex * pageSize), take: pageSize },
        success: function (posts) {
            var items = '';
            $.each(posts, function(p, post) {
                items += 'html removed to keep post short';
            });

            var $itemBlock = $(items);
            $allF.append($itemBlock);
            $allF.imagesLoaded(function () {
                $allF.masonry('appended', $itemBlock);
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Although, do I need to have the extra$allF.masonry('appended', $itemBlock); after the imagesLoaded check?  I've removed it and appears to work fine.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly left that line. Deleting that.